# JavaFX, не могу поставить иконку в TreeView

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

Изображения видимы, но не ставятся на TreeItem:

Код

```
package Application;

import java.io.File;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class FileSeeker extends TreeItem<File> {
    Image icon = new Image(FileSeeker.class.getResourceAsStream("ImagesAndCss/foldclose16.png"));
    Image image = new Image(FileSeeker.class.getResourceAsStream("ImagesAndCss/foldopen16.png"));

    public FileSeeker(File file) {
        super(file);
    }

    public FileSeeker(File file, ImageView imageview) {
        super(file, imageview);
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<TreeItem<File>> getChildren() {
        if (isFirstChildren) {
            isFirstChildren = false;
            super.getChildren().setAll(buildFoldersAndFiles(this));
        }
        return super.getChildren();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLeaf() {
        if (isFirstLeaf) {
            isFirstLeaf = false;
            File f = (File) getValue();
            isLeaf = f.isFile();
        }
        return isLeaf;
    }

    private ObservableList<TreeItem<File>> buildFoldersAndFiles(TreeItem<File> treeItem) {
        File f = treeItem.getValue();
        f.getName();
        if (treeItem.getValue().isDirectory()) {
            treeItem.setGraphic(new ImageView(icon));
        } else {
            treeItem.setGraphic(new ImageView(image));
        }
        if (f != null) {
            File[] files = f.listFiles();
            ObservableList<TreeItem<File>> children = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

            for (File childFile : files) {
                if (childFile.isDirectory()) {
                    FileSeeker fs = new FileSeeker(childFile);
                    fs.setGraphic(new ImageView(icon));
                    children.add(fs);
                } else {
                    FileSeeker fs = new FileSeeker(childFile);
                    System.out.println(image.equals(null));
                    fs.setGraphic(new ImageView(image));
                    children.add(fs);
                }
            }
            return children;
        }
        return FXCollections.emptyObservableList();
    }

    private boolean isFirstChildren = true;
    private boolean isFirstLeaf = true;
    private boolean isLeaf;
}
```

Приложение

```
package Application;

import java.io.File;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.effect.InnerShadow;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

//Основное окно
public class FileManager extends Application {
    Image ico = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("ImagesAndCss/gnome_text_x_generic.png"));
    FileSeeker fseek = new FileSeeker(new File("C:\\"));
    TreeView<File> treeview = new TreeView<File>(fseek);

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        String css = FileManager.class.getResource("ImagesAndCss/Main.css").toExternalForm();
        String icon = FileManager.class.getResource("ImagesAndCss/folder-documents-icon.png").toExternalForm();

        final Label warn = new Label("Выберите Каталог");
        Button addDirectory = new Button("Создать каталог (F7)");
        addDirectory.setId("AddDir");
        fseek.setExpanded(true);
        fseek.setGraphic(new ImageView(ico));
        BorderPane spane = new BorderPane();
        spane.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: white;-fx-background-color: #24011F;");

        HBox But = new HBox();

        Scene scene = new Scene(spane, 600, 600);

        scene.getStylesheets().add(css);

        Label root = new Label("C:\\");
        root.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: white;");
        warn.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: yellow;");

        reduceNames(treeview);

        addDirectory.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                try{

                File f = treeview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getValue();
                if(f == null || !f.isDirectory()){
                    warn.setText("Ошибка.Вы выбрали файл, а не Директорию");
                } else {
                    warn.setText("");
                final Stage addDirStage = new AddDirectory(primaryStage,f.getAbsolutePath() + "\\Новый Каталог");
                addDirStage.show();
                }
                }catch(NullPointerException e) {
                    warn.setText("Директория не выбрана!");
                }
            }
        });

        But.getChildren().addAll(addDirectory,warn);

        spane.setTop(root);
        spane.setCenter(treeview);
        spane.setBottom(But);

        madeShadow(treeview,50);
        madeShadow(But,2);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Файловый менеджер");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(icon));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    //Обрезает имена файлов и каталогов
    public void reduceNames(TreeView<File> treeview) {
        treeview.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<File>, TreeCell<File>>() {
            public TreeCell<File> call(TreeView<File> tv) {
                return new TreeCell<File>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(File item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        setText((empty || item == null) ? "" : item.getName());
                    }
                };
            }
        });
    }

    //Дополнительное окно с добавлением каталога
    public class AddDirectory extends Stage {
        public AddDirectory(Stage parent,final String path) {
            initOwner(parent);
            initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);

            String iconAdd = FileManager.class.getResource("ImagesAndCss/kde_add_folder_to_archive.png").toExternalForm();

            BorderPane bpane = new BorderPane();
            bpane.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: white; -fx-background-color: #24011F; ");

            HBox buts = new HBox(5);
            HBox addField = new HBox();

            Button add = new Button("Создать");
            Button cancel = new Button("Отмена");

            add.setStyle("-fx-color: green;");
            cancel.setStyle("-fx-color: red;");

            Label pathl = new Label("Путь Каталога: ");
            pathl.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: white");

            final TextField enterpath = new TextField(path);

            enterpath.setMinWidth(400);
            enterpath.setMaxWidth(600);

            buts.getChildren().addAll(add,cancel);
            addField.getChildren().addAll(pathl,enterpath);
            bpane.setBottom(buts);
            bpane.setCenter(addField);

            add.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    File f = new File(enterpath.getText());
                    System.out.println(enterpath.getText());
                    if(!f.exists()){
                        f.mkdir();
                        close();
                    }
                }
            });

            cancel.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    close();
                }
            });

            Scene scene = new Scene(bpane, 500, 100);
            setResizable(false);
            setScene(scene);
            getIcons().add(new Image(iconAdd));
            setTitle("Добавить каталог");
        }
    }

    //Эффект внутренней тени
    public void madeShadow(Node node, double res){
        InnerShadow insh = new InnerShadow(res, Color.BLACK);
        node.setEffect(insh);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Css

```
.tree-cell:hover .highlight-on-hover {
    -fx-text-fill: red ;
}

.tree-cell  {
    -fx-background-color: "#24011F";
     -fx-text-fill: white ;
}

#AddDir {
    -fx-color: green;
}

#Warning {
    -fx-color: red;
}

.MainTheme {
    -fx-background-color: "#24011F";
     -fx-text-fill: white ;
}
```

[image: Нет иконок]

Было

```
public void reduceNames(TreeView<File> treeview) {
    treeview.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<File>, TreeCell<File>>() {
        public TreeCell<File> call(TreeView<File> tv) {
            return new TreeCell<File>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(File item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    setText((empty || item == null) ? "" : item.getName());
                }
            };
        }
    });
}
```

Стало

```
public void reduceNames(TreeView<File> treeview) {
    treeview.setCellFactory(new Callback<TreeView<File>, TreeCell<File>>() {
        public TreeCell<File> call(TreeView<File> tv) {
            return new TreeCell<File>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(File item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    setText((empty || item == null) ? "" : item.getName());
               this.setGraphic(this.getTreeItem().getGraphic());
                }
            };
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под "изображения видимы, но не ставятся в TreeItem" ?

Comment: 1.При проверке на null перед привязкой к TreeItem я получаю False, то есть объект Image создаётся и видим приложением.
2. При создании тестового TreeView<String> иконка ставится прекрасно

Comment: так вы сами же и написали, что иконка вставляется. В чем проблема то?

Comment: Иконка вставлялась на тестовом TreeView который я заполнял вручную, и ставил Иконки также вручную, но мне нужно расставить иконки для файлового менеджера, который собирается из методов расположенных выше, файлы и папки собираются прекрасно, но иконки не добавляются

Comment: Создал тестовый пример, в котором создал treeView и проставил в root новый FileSeeker(new File('.')) и все отработало прекрано. Добавьте минимальный пример для показа неисправности

Comment: Добавил, иконок нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проблема заключается в том, что при отрисовке ( т.е. когда у вас идет вызов `setCellFactory`) вы проставляете только текст `setText()` и поэтому иконки у вас не рисуются.

Возможные варианты решения проблемы.

1. Не проставляйте свою фактори. ( просто удалите вызов метода `reduceNames(treeView)`)
2. В фактори вызывать еще метод this.setGraphic(this.getTreeItem().getGraphic()), в которую вы будете передавать иконку.

   ```
   @Override
   protected void updateItem(File item, boolean empty) {
       super.updateItem(item, empty);

       // этой строки не было
       setGraphic((empty || item == null) ? null : this.getTreeItem().getGraphic());

       setText((empty || item == null) ? "" : item.getName());
   }
   ```

Comment: Простите за то что утомляю вас, мало опыта в десктопе, последнее скажите пожалуйста, как именно я должен изменить метод reduceNames(treeView) чтобы сохранить его и оставить иконки?
Было - Стало

Comment: @Lukashman см апдейт

Comment: Прекрасно! Всё работает!